# Is there a way to restrict user to access only Tactical Overview in Nagios?

Tags: nagios

Is there a way for me to configure Nagios to allow user to access only "Tactical Overview" (`/nagios/cgi-bin/tac.cgi`) through `cgi.cfg`?

```
# grep ^authorized_for_ /etc/nagios/cgi.cfg
authorized_for_system_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_configuration_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_system_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagiosadmin
#
```

Answer (score 6):

Through Nagios?  Not that I'm aware of.  You could probably hack your apache configuration to allow it, though.

(Full disclosure:  I haven't tested this.)

Maybe something like

```
<DirectoryMatch (/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs|/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3|/etc/nagios3
/stylesheets)>
        Options FollowSymLinks

        DirectoryIndex index.php

        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All

        AuthName "Nagios Access"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users
        AuthGroupFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.groups
                <files index.php|side.php|tac.cgi>
                        require group ViewTac
                </files>
        require group FullAccess
</DirectoryMatch>
```

combined with separating the users into [groups](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) would do what you're looking for.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it through Apache as well, just from looking at your example, you're missing `AuthGroupFile`, but I get the idea..

Comment: Yeah.  I went ahead and added it.  :)